# Asynchronicity issue with an Angular 2 app and the Angular 2 router

Tags: asynchronous, angular, rxjs, angular2-routing, ngrx

I am facing a **tricky issue with asynchronicity** in an angular 2 app.

I am basically trying to rehydrate/reload information from the backend when the app is reloaded/bootstrapped in the user's browser (think F5/refresh). The issue is that before the backend async method returns the result, a router guard is called and blocks...

I reload the information from the root component's `ngOnInit` method as follows:

from root component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    //reloadPersonalInfo returns an Observable
    this.sessionService.reloadPersonalInfo()
      .subscribe();
  }
```

from `sessionService`:

```
  reloadPersonalInfo() {
    //FIRST: the app execution flow gets here
    let someCondition: boolean = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someCondition'));
    if (someCondition) {
      return this.userAccountService.retrieveCurrentUserAccount()
        .switchMap(currentUserAccount => {
          //THIRD: and finally, the execution flow will get there and set the authenticated state to true (unfortunately too late)...
          this.store.dispatch({type: SET_AUTHENTICATED});
          this.store.dispatch({type: SET_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT, payload: currentUserAccount});
          return Observable.of('');
        });
    }
    return Observable.empty();
  }
```

The trouble is that I have a router `CanActivate` guard as follows:

```
  canActivate() {
    //SECOND: then the execution flow get here and because reloadPersonalInfo has not completed yet, isAuthenticated will return false and the guard will block and redirect to '/signin'
    const isAuthenticated = this.sessionService.isAuthenticated();
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
    }
    return isAuthenticated;
  }
```

isAuthenticated method from `sessionService`:

```
  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    let isAuthenticated = false;
    this.store.select(s => s.authenticated)
      .subscribe(authenticated => isAuthenticated = authenticated);
    return isAuthenticated;
  }
```

So to recap:

1. FIRST: the `reloadPersonalInfo` method on `sessionService` is called by root component `ngOnInit`. The execution flow enters this method.
2. SECOND: in the meantime, the router guard is called and sees that the state of  `authenticated` is `false` (because `reloadPersonalInfo` has not completed yet and therefore not set the `authenticated` state to `true`.
3. THIRD: `reloadPersonalInfo` completes **too late** and sets the `authenticated` state to `true` (but the router guard has already blocked).

Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**: Let me stress that the `authenticated` state that matters is the one in the store; it is set by this line: `this.store.dispatch({type: SET_AUTHENTICATED});`.

**edit 2**: I changed the condition from `authenticated` to `someCondition` in order to reduce confusion. Previously, there was another state variable called `authenticated`...

**edit 3**: I have changed the `isAuthenticated()` method return type to `Observable<boolean>` instead of `boolean` (to follow Martin's advice) and adapted the `canActivate` method as follows:

```
 canActivate() {
    return this.sessionService.isAuthenticated().map(isAuthenticated => {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        return true;
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
      return false;
    });
  }
```

from `sessionService`:

```
  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(s => s.authenticated);
  }
```

It makes no difference unfortunately...

Can someone please advise as to how to sort this asynchronicity issue?

Comment: I have to somehow find a way for `reloadPersonalInfo()` to complete before the router guard runs... Asynchronicity sometimes is hard on us!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be two possible ways to solve this:

#### Solution 1

The quickest, would be to distinguish your `isAuthenticated` not into 2 but 3 states, this way you can encode one more cruical piece of information into the state: At the time of bootstrapping(when no response from the server has been received), there is no way the client can know for sure if its credentials/tokens are valid or not, thus the state should correctly be "unknown".

First you have to change the initial state of `authenticated` in your store to `null` (you also may choose `undefined` or even use numbers depending on your personal taste). And then you just have to add a `.filter` to your guard, that renders the guard practically "motionless":

```
canActivate() {
    return this.sessionService.isAuthenticated()
        .filter(isAuthenticated => isAuthenticated !== null) // this will cause the guard to halt until the isAuthenticated-question/request has been resolved
        .do(isAuth => (if (!isAuth) {this.router.navigate(['/signin'])}));
}
```

---

#### Solution 2

The second solution would be very similar, but instead of encoding a 3rd state into `authenticated` you'd add a new flag to your store called `authRequestRunning`, that is set to `true` while the auth-request is being made, and set to `false` after it completes. Your guard would then look only slightly different:

```
canActivate() {
    return this.sessionService.isAuthenticated()
        .switchMap(isAuth => this.sessionService.isAuthRequestRunning()
            .filter(running => !running) // don't emit any data, while the request is running
            .mapTo(isAuth);
        )
        .do(isAuth => (if (!isAuth) {this.router.navigate(['/signin'])}));
}
```

With solution #2 you might have some more code. <s>and you have to be careful that the `authRequestRunning` is set to `false` **first** before the `authenticated`-state is updated.</s>

*Edit:* I have edited the code in solution #2, so the order of setting the running-status and the auth-status does **not** matter any more.

The reason why I would use solution #2 is, because in most cases such a state-flag already exists and is being used to display a loading-indicator or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

why are you not setting Authenticated before you give a `retrieveCurrentUserAccount` call? IT seems you already know if your user is authenticated or not based upon the value inside `localStorage`

```
if (isAuthenticated) {
      // set before you give a async call.
      this.store.dispatch({type: SET_AUTHENTICATED});
      return this.userAccountService.retrieveCurrentUserAccount()
        .switchMap(currentUserAccount => {
          //THIRD: and finally, the execution flow will get there and set the authenticated state to true (unfortunately too late)...             
          this.store.dispatch({type: SET_CURRENT_USER_ACCOUNT, payload: currentUserAccount});
          return Observable.of('');
        });
    }
```

**Update**

Try below,

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Routes, RouterModule, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService{
   private _isAuthenticated: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  public get isAuthenticated(){
    return this._isAuthenticated.asObservable();
  }

  reloadPersonalInfo(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._isAuthenticated.next(true);
      // do something else too...
    }, 2000);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h3>Angular CanActivate observable</h3>
  <hr />
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, 
     private sessionService : SessionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionService.reloadPersonalInfo();
  }
}

@Component({
  template: '<h3>Dashboard</h3>'
})
export class DashboardComponent { }

@Component({
  template: '<h3>Login</h3>'
})
export class LoginComponent { }

@Injectable()
export class DashboardAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private sessionService : SessionService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
      return this.sessionService.isAuthenticated.map(res => {
        if(res){
          return true;
        }
       this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }).take(1);
    }
}

let routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [DashboardAuthGuard],
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
   {
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent
  }
]

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  DashboardAuthGuard
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders 
= RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/2rXrdNJ6K7a3GsiqmlGv?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, I actually need to wait until the `currentUserAccount` has been retrieved before I dispatch the `SET_AUTHENTICATED` action (which sets the `authenticated` boolean state read by the router guard).

Comment: can you explain your usecase more? because what i see it seems you are reading the info from local storage.

Comment: Also, as mentioned in my edit, the authenticated boolean that the router guard is based on is not the one in local storage.

Comment: Yes. I do have more than one `authenticated` variables here... which is a bit confusing.

Comment: I changed the less relevant variable's name to `someCondition` in order to reduce confusion.

Comment: @balteo updated the solution and added a Plunker, Hope that helps, Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Madhu, No not yet. I am trying to adapt the solution you kindly suggested. Bear with me.

Comment: Hi Madhu, Can you please explain your solution, the constructs you have used and what differences with my code allow it to work?

Comment: Hi Madhu, the trouble with setting the authenticated state in the store as follows  `this.store.dispatch({type: SET_AUTHENTICATED});` and especially before the http call, is that if the http call fails then the app is left in a weird state...

Answer (score 0):

`canActivate` itself can return an Observable.

Instead of returning the boolean result in `canActivate`, return the `isAuthenticated` Observable.

Comment: Hi, Even if I return an `Observable<boolean>`, the `retrieveCurrentUserAccount` method might very well not complete before the `isAuthenticated` method. The issue therefore remains.

Comment: I have edited my post to take into account your suggestion.